# Liberator Custom Not Authorized Message

Tags: clojure, liberator

How do I pass in a custom `401 Not Authorized` message when `:not-authorized?` is true? I'd like to show a more useful message like `Key must have admin permissions`.

Comment: when you do ajax request you can check the status if it is 401 you can set the new custom message for it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to take a look at [handlers](http://clojure-liberator.github.io/liberator/doc/handlers.html):

> For every http status code there is a handler function defined in liberator. All have sensible defaults and will return a simple english error message or an empty response, whatever is appropriate.

In your case you need to provide your own handler for `:handle-unauthorized` key:

```
(defresource my-resource
  ...
  :handle-unauthorized (fn [ctx] ...))
```